# generate random number larger than given number until infinity in java

Tags: java

I want to generate a random number between a given number and infinity in Java.
I know this way to generate random number between `0` and `100`:

```
int rand = (int) (Math.random() * 100 + (0));
```

But I need to generate a random number larger than 0 until infinity:

```
int rand = (int) (Math.random() * infinity + (m + 1));
```

Comment: do you have infinite memory to save your generated number?

Comment: There is no standard notion of "random positive integer" (or "random integer larger than 100") since there is no such thing as a uniform probability distribution on the set of natural numbers. Thus, your problem isn't adequately defined. You need to specify what you want the distribution to be.

Comment: You will need to work within not just the reasonable limitations of the machine but also practicality. Using java biginteger you can create quite large numbers. But I have to point out given an upper bound of infinity quite a lot of random numbers are going to be impractically large.

Comment: How about you explain what you're really trying to do? We know you're not attempting to create an infinitely large random number, because that makes no sense.

Comment: I will generate you one and will encrypt it by muliplying it by 0. Then you just have to devide it by 0 and you should have it in your code, isn't it

Comment: If you wrote such a program, by definition it could never reach infinity anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no such thing as infinity in programming, but you can use Integer.MAX_VALUE which is basically the same.

You can read about it here: [https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html)

Comment: I don't think that `2^31 - 1` is "basically the same" as infinity, even in programming.

Comment: 2^31 - 1 is the maximum integer that can be encoded in a program, if you can't encode anymore integers than 2^31 - 1, you can consider 2^31 - 1 an infinity or an infinite big number if you prefer

Comment: `2^31-1` is the maximum 32-bit signed integer. With a `BigInteger` you can represent vastly larger integers.

Comment: Well that's also a possibility, I'd go for either. Since you can't really have infinite memory to keep infinite numbers